# Short story on British radio about fish gutters turned contract killers

Tags: identification-request

One weekend evening in late 2010, I heard a short story on British radio (probably BBC Radio 4) whose main characters were two women (I think Scottish?), one of them the first-person narrator. The story went as follows. Since I don't remember their names at all, I'm going to use A and B to refer to the two characters for simplicity.

- The opening sentence was something gorey sounding, like "being up to our elbows in guts", but in the next sentence it was established that they were just doing their everyday work in a fish factory.
- They are dissatisfied with their jobs and their lives. The viewpoint character (A) specifically bemoans her old television set on which she likes to watch *Sex and the City*.
- The second character (B) is established as someone who likes to tell tall tales, I think often involving glamorous new jobs. A habitually humours her in these stories.
- Today, B claims to have got a new career as an "**international contract killer**". (I specifically remember this phrase, spoken in a Scottish accent.) A continues to humour her, not believing a word of it.
- After work, they get into B's car and go to the shops. A notices something under a blanket on the back seat, and B says it's a dead body. I think she claims to have killed a man with a rolling pin. A still doesn't believe a word of it.
- While B is in the shop (I think), A gets curious and lifts up the blanket. Another specific phrase I remember: "**It was a man. He was dead.**" A begins screaming, and tells B she'll have to call the police.
- B convinces A not to call the police and instead to help her dispose of the body, saying this will be the last time and she won't kill anyone else.
- They bury the body together. B does something which shows how much money she earned for this murder (maybe pulling out a fancy new phone?) A asks what was the fee.
- When B tells her how much she got for killing this man, and how much A's cut will be just for helping to bury the body, A decides to join B in this new business. The last line of the story is something like: "**I might be going to hell, but at least I'll have a dirty great plasma-screen telly to watch *Sex and the City* on while I wait!**"

It might be ["The Fishwife's Lament"](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00c83jm), but I can't find any information about this story online to confirm the plot.

What was this story, and does any extant recording or written version of it exist?